# Ubuntu LVM LUKS Encryption

Tags: encryption, linux, disk-encryption

I've been reading about Ubuntu [LVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_Volume_Manager_%28Linux%29) Encryption, and I understand that it supports the use of [*Linux Unified Key Setup* (LUKS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Unified_Key_Setup) during installation, which is a block level encryption that encrypts the entire logical volume.

Is it possible to read files on the encrypted volume when I boot the system with rescue media or a live CD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but only if you provide the encryption key/passphrase used to encrypt the data.  Without the key, the data is inaccessible, and the device appears as (essentially) noise.

Answer (score 2):

You can open open device with

```
cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/where_ever whatever_loop_device
```

Then mount the loop device. Passphrase will be required at stage 1.